# selenium web driver wait until page to refresh

Tags: selenium-webdriver, wait, page-refresh

Below is the code snippet of my selenium test case, where i use select method to choose a value from the drop down . And the next step would be clicking on the submit . But by the time i try to click on the submit button the page is not refreshed(which will refresh the same page), throwing

> element not clickable,StaleElementReference exception

. The only solution which works for me is `thread.sleep()`.

I tried all the below options but had no luck :(

`explicit wait()`,`wait.until(Exceptedcontions.visibility)`,`element to be clickable()` etc , tried all the solutions on th web .

I had to use `thread.sleep()` 3-4 times in a test case and i have around 100 test cases which is costing a lot of time .

Any working solutions where the web driver waits until the page gets completely refreshed and DOM loads completely before clicking on the submit button.

```
@Test
@Timeout(group = Group.SLOW)
public void testProvider() throws InterruptedException {

    proceedToProvider();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchId"))).selectByVisibleText("Search");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();
    timeSplit("Search submitted");
```

Below is the error i see when i use other solutions.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (1289, 141). Other element would receive the click:
>   
>   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 168 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.49.1', revision:
>   '808c23b0963853d375cbe54b90bbd052e2528a54', time: '2016-01-21
>   09:37:52' System info: host: 'ALAKASIMA01-W7L', ip: '10.145.45.233',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_73' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\kasima01\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6628_12218},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=XP,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   8bf0b4cc7efc715015509f4be345d14d

Answer (score 0):

```
public void WaitForElementToLoad(String selector, String key, String seconds)
            throws ValidationException {

        Integer time = Integer.valueOf(seconds);

        WebElement element = null;

        while (time > 0) {

            try {
                element = getSpecificWebElement(selector, key);

                break;
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                time--;
            }
        }

        if (element == null && time <= 0) {
              // throw your own exception
        }
    }
```

Above method shows one of the basic ways to do this. `getSpecificWebElement` is a method can be defined by yourself to use findElementByXX and throw your own exception for catching. Pass the upper limit second you would wait for specific element.

There is also another solution - use `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

> Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present.

**Update:**

I think I'd better post `getSpecificWebElement`

```
private WebElement getSpecificWebElement(String selector, String key)
            throws ValidationException {
        WebElement element = null;

        String expression = "";

        By by = composeSelector(selector, key);

        try {
            element = FindElementBy(by);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

            throw new ValidationException("not found " + expression);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ValidationException(
                    Exceptions.getShortStackTraceAsString(e));
        }

        return element;
}


private WebElement FindElementBy(By by) {

        final By selector = by;

        ExpectedCondition<WebElement> ec = new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {

            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {

                return driver.findElement(selector);

            }

        };

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        return wait.until(ec);
    }
```

In this case the waiting time is enough, would be X(the passed seconds value) * 10.

Comment: @Test
 @Timeout(group = Group.SLOW)
 public void testProviderSearchDataShareOn() throws InterruptedException, ValidationException {

  proceedToProviderScreen();
  new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchId"))).selectByVisibleText("Search");
//  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WaitForElementToLoad("id","btnSubmit","20");                                                     Same element not clickable error .

Comment: Consider some elements are covering your target element. You need to remove the barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will check entire page is loaded?

```
    static void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver wdriver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wdriver, 60);

    Predicate<WebDriver> pageLoaded = new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) input).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }

    };
    wait.until(pageLoaded);
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: No luck , As soon as new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchId"))).selectByVisibleText("Search");     is executed , the driver is throwing element not clickable exception .

Comment: Did you call waitForPageLoad before select statement?

Comment: I am actually getting the error after the select statement . I tried waitForPageLoad () before click() on process button .

Comment: Try this  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnSubmit"));

    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();